# Pylint for half-implemented abstract classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pylint

Consider following code snippet:

```
class AbstractClass(object):
    def method1(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def method2(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class SemiConcreteClass(AbstractClass):
    def method1(self):
        return True

class ConcreteClass(SemiConcreteClass):
    def method2(self):
        return True
```

Running checks on this file with default config (`pylint classes.py`) yields some missing docstrings (let's ignore them) and this warning:

> W:  8, 0: Method 'method2' is abstract in class 'AbstractClass' but is
>   not overridden (abstract-method)

I know `SemiConcreteClass` is in fact abstract and should be sub-classed in order to be used and I do not want Pylint to report it. How can I configure Pylint to treat these classes as just another abstract class? Naming convention of class name, module where class resides - all this solutions would be fine.

I know I can explicitly silence warning in class by `# pylint: disable=abstract-method` comment. Is there more elegant solution?

```
pylint 1.4.3,
astroid 1.3.6, common 0.63.2
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Looks like a known [bug in pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/179).

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately pylint is not really intelligent enough in cases like these, personally I would just disable the warning since `ConcreteClass` obviously implements both. The alternative solution would be to make `SemiConcreteClass` implement both methods but that's usually something you are trying to avoid.

Instead of having Pylint check for this I usually just use the [Python Abstract Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) instead, they will notify you of unimplemented methods.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import abc


class AbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method1(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method2(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class SemiConcreteClass(AbstractClass):
    def method1(self):
        return True


SemiConcreteClass()
```

Which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 22, in <module>
    SemiConcreteClass()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class SemiConcreteClass with abstract methods method2
```